# Not able to query(from Hive) Parquet file created in Pig

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, parquet

I have create a Parquet file in Pig(in the directory `outputset`)

```
grunt> STORE extracted INTO './outputset' USING ParquetStorer;
```

The file has `1 Record` as shown below,

```
grunt> mydata = LOAD './outputset/part-r-00000.parquet' using ParquetLoader;
grunt> dump mydata;
(val1,val2,val3)
grunt> describe mydata;
mydata: {val_0: chararray,val_1: chararray,val_2: chararray}
```

After this, I have created an external table in **Hive** to read this file,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test (
 field1 string,
 field2 string,
 field3 string) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/home/.../outputset';
```

When I query the table I am able to retrieve the `1 Record,` but all the fields are `NULL` as show below,

```
hive> select * from parquet_test;
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

What am I missing here?

PS :

```
Pig version : 0.15.0
Hive version : 1.2.1
```

Comment: Are the datatypes of `val1`, `val2`, and `val3` `chararray`?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 yes val1, val2 & val3 are chararray

Answer (score 0):

You need to match exact field name in pig with column in hive.

```
So your hive should look like
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test (
 val1 string,
 val2 string,
 val3 string) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/home/.../outputset';
```